# Jpa named native query no result

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa, hibernate-native-query

I'm trying to connect a java spring cloud microservice to an oracle database.
my problem is that when I call a native query passing the parameters from function this does not return anything to me, while if I insert its parameters directly in the query everything works.

ENTITY

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "######")
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name    = "EmployeeJobDTO",
        classes = @ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = EmployeeJobDTO.class,
                columns     = {
                        @ColumnResult(name = "idStf",           type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "personalNumber",  type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "name",            type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "surname",         type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "functionMain",    type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "idDrr",           type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "functionShift",   type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "shiftOldCode",    type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "shiftCode",       type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "idJob",           type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "jobType",         type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "jobStatus",       type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "plannedFrom",     type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "plannedTo",       type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "actualFrom",      type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "actualTo",        type = String.class)
                }) 
        )
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
            name                = "findDayJobsByDateAndDepartment",
            resultClass         = EmployeeJobDTO.class,
            resultSetMapping    = "EmployeeJobDTO",
            query   = "select to_char(st.XXXX) as idStf," + 
                    "st.XXXX as personalNumber," + 
                    "st.XXXX as name," + 
                    "st.XXXX as surname," + 
                    "sp.XXXX as functionMain," + 
                    "dr.XXXX as idDrr," + 
                    "dr.XXXX as functionShift," + 
                    "dr.XXXX as shiftOldCode," + 
                    "dr.XXXX as shiftCode," + 
                    "jb.XXXX as idJob," + 
                    "jb.XXXX as jobType," + 
                    "substr(jb.XXXX, 0, 1) as jobStatus," + 
                    "jb.XXXX as plannedFrom," + 
                    "jb.XXXX as plannedTo," + 
                    "jb.XXXX as actualFrom," + 
                    "jb.XXXX as actualTo " + 
                    "from XXXXXX jb " + 
                    "inner join XXXXXX dr on jb.XXXX = dr.XXXX " + 
                    "inner join XXXXXX st on jb.XXXX = st.XXXX " + 
                    "inner join XXXXXX sr on sr.XXXX = jb.XXXX " + 
                    "inner join XXXXXX sp on sp.XXXX = jb.XXXX " +
                    "where dr.XXXX=?1 and dr.XXXX = 'A' and sr.XXXX=?2"
            ),
    @NamedNativeQuery(
            name                = "findDayJobsByDateAndDepartmentFixedParam",
            resultClass         = EmployeeJobDTO.class,
            resultSetMapping    = "EmployeeJobDTO",
            query   = "select to_char(st.XXXX) as idStf," + 
                    "st.XXXX as personalNumber," + 
                    "st.XXXX as name," + 
                    "st.XXXX as surname," + 
                    "sp.XXXX as functionMain," + 
                    "dr.XXXX as idDrr," + 
                    "dr.XXXX as functionShift," + 
                    "dr.XXXX as shiftOldCode," + 
                    "dr.XXXX as shiftCode," + 
                    "jb.XXXX as idJob," + 
                    "jb.XXXX as jobType," + 
                    "substr(jb.XXXX, 0, 1) as jobStatus," + 
                    "jb.XXXX as plannedFrom," + 
                    "jb.XXXX as plannedTo," + 
                    "jb.XXXX as actualFrom," + 
                    "jb.XXXX as actualTo " + 
                    "from XXXXXX jb " + 
                    "inner join XXXXXX dr on jb.XXXX = dr.XXXX " + 
                    "inner join XXXXXX st on jb.XXXX = st.XXXX " + 
                    "inner join XXXXXX sr on sr.XXXX = jb.XXXX " + 
                    "inner join XXXXXX sp on sp.XXXX = jb.XXXX " +
                    "where dr.XXXX='20200224' and dr.XXXX = 'A' and sr.XXXX='SFA'"
            )
})
public class EmployeeJobEntity {
    //.............. follows the code .....
}
```

REPOSITORY

```
public interface EmployeeJobEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<EmployeeJobEntity, String> {
    // This query return [] i tryed @Param annotation and the result not change.
    @Query(name = "findDayJobsByDateAndDepartment", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<EmployeeJobDTO> findDayJobsByDateAndDepartment(String date, String department);

    // This query return the data OK
    @Query(name = "findDayJobsByDateAndDepartmentFixedParam", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<EmployeeJobDTO> findDayJobsByDateAndDepartmentFixedParam();
}
```

APPLICATION.YML

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      hibernate:
        SQL: DEBUG
        type:
          descriptor:
            sql:
              BasicBinder: TRACE
server:
  port: 8100
spring:
  application:
    name: employee
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXXX-XXX.XX.it:<port>:<sid>
    password: XXXX
    username: XXXX
    hikari:
      connection-test-query: select 1 from dual
      minimum-idle: 1
      idle-timeout: 240000
      max-lifetime: 360000
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      pool-name: XXXX
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

POM.XML DEPENDENCIES

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

LOG CONSOLE

```
[springProfile_IS_UNDEFINED] - [DEBUG] 2020-02-25 08:47:20 [http-nio-8100-exec-2] o.h.SQL - [employee,] 
    select
        to_char(st.XXXX) as idStf,
        st.XXXX as personalNumber,
        st.XXXX as name,
        st.XXXX as surname,
        sp.XXXX as functionMain,
        dr.XXXX as idDrr,
        dr.XXXX as functionShift,
        dr.XXXX as shiftOldCode,
        dr.XXXX as shiftCode,
        jb.XXXX as idJob,
        jb.XXXX as jobType,
        substr(jb.XXXX,
        0,
        1) as jobStatus,
        jb.XXXX as plannedFrom,
        jb.XXXX as plannedTo,
        jb.XXXX as actualFrom,
        jb.XXXX as actualTo 
    from
        XXXXXX jb 
    inner join
        XXXXXX dr 
            on jb.XXXX = dr.XXXX 
    inner join
        XXXXXX st 
            on jb.XXXX = st.XXXX 
    inner join
        XXXXXX sr 
            on sr.XXXX = jb.XXXX 
    inner join
        XXXXXX sp 
            on sp.XXXX = jb.XXXX 
    where
        dr.XXXX =? 
        and dr.XXXX = 'A' 
        and sr.XXXX =?
[springProfile_IS_UNDEFINED] - [TRACE] 2020-02-25 08:47:20 [http-nio-8100-exec-2] o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder - [employee,] binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [20200224]
[springProfile_IS_UNDEFINED] - [TRACE] 2020-02-25 08:47:20 [http-nio-8100-exec-2] o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder - [employee,] binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [SFA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use spring's annotation @Param, for your case, code looks like:

```
@Query(name = "findDayJobsByDateAndDepartment", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<EmployeeJobDTO> findDayJobsByDateAndDepartment(@Param("date") String date, @Param("department") String department);
```

More references about Spring JPA in this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have already tried using the @Param annotations but the result does not change.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by modifying the query, the department field is a char [8].

```
    query   = "select to_char(st.XXXX) as idStf," + 
            "st.XXXX as personalNumber," + 
            "st.XXXX as name," + 
            "st.XXXX as surname," + 
            "sp.XXXX as functionMain," + 
            "dr.XXXX as idDrr," + 
            "dr.XXXX as functionShift," + 
            "dr.XXXX as shiftOldCode," + 
            "dr.XXXX as shiftCode," + 
            "jb.XXXX as idJob," + 
            "jb.XXXX as jobType," + 
            "substr(jb.XXXX, 0, 1) as jobStatus," + 
            "jb.XXXX as plannedFrom," + 
            "jb.XXXX as plannedTo," + 
            "jb.XXXX as actualFrom," + 
            "jb.XXXX as actualTo " + 
            "from XXXXXX jb " + 
            "inner join XXXXXX dr on jb.XXXX = dr.XXXX " + 
            "inner join XXXXXX st on jb.XXXX = st.XXXX " + 
            "inner join XXXXXX sr on sr.XXXX = jb.XXXX " + 
            "inner join XXXXXX sp on sp.XXXX = jb.XXXX " +
            "where dr.XXXX=:date and dr.XXXX = 'A' and trim(sr.XXXX) = :department"
```

I can't understand why by sculpting the fields in the query the error didn't happen!